# Functional Test - Event is not received when test run on release mode on debug mode works fine

Tags: c#, debugging, events, testing, snmp

I have got following Functional Test. Test purpose is to check if my SNMP Manager works correctly after SNMP Trap message being triggered.

**The problem is, my test is working fine only in debug mode.**

I tried to use "ManualResetEvent" and also "Thread.Sleep" to help **event** being received by "Manager".

```
[TestMethod]
public void SendingTrap_To_Running_SnmpManager()
{
    _sut.Engine.Start();
    bool trapReciverHandlerWasTriggered = false;

    _sut.WatcherTrapV2ReceivedDelegate = (sender, args) =>
    {
        trapReciverHandlerWasTriggered = true;
    };

     Messenger.SendTrapV2(//args are not imporant in this case);

    Thread.Sleep(2000);

    Assert.IsTrue(trapReciverHandlerWasTriggered, "Trap was not recived by SNMP-Manager.");
     _sut.Engine.Stop();
}
```

### Follow,Up: In case someone run on this thread.

- Binaries [Release/Debug] are fine, problem lays in different place.
- Background thread which is track outside of main test thread throws exception which was a root of the problem.

Comment: Check the dates of the executable in the debug and release (and x86 if it exists) folder to make sure release was rebuilt.  If not, change the pulldown in VS and rebuild in Release instead of Debug (or x86).

Comment: I rebuild / and changed pullback don't help me.

Comment: Make a copy of Bin folder and then delete bin.  Then rebuild.  The dependencies in the compiler may not be rebuilding everything.  You may be getting an exception that was handled properly in debug but not in release.  Do you have any exception handlers in your code?  Put at least one in the Main function as a default to help you debug issue.

Comment: Ok problem is rather different than I though on beginning. The message is sent on other thread than the Test is working. The other thread goes exception but test passes anyway, any idea how can I somehow force UT to run on one thread ?